# NLTK - Stopwords, hashing over list

Tags: python, list, nltk

I'll try to make this as easy to understand as possible as I can imagine how infuriating long and drawn-out problems can become.

I have a list of tweets, all stored within a variable called 'all_tweets'. (This is because some tweets fell into the 'text' category, while others fell into 'extended_tweet', so I had to merge them together.

I tokenised the tweets, and it all worked perfectly. I got a list of each tweet and each word within a tweet all seperated.

I am trying to now implement stopwords into the code so I can filter out, you guessed it, any stopwords.

My code is as follows:

```
wordVec = [nltk.word_tokenize(tweet) for tweet in all_tweets]
stopWords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
wordsFiltered = []

for w in wordVec:
    if w not in stopWords:
        wordsFiltered.append(w)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-ae7a97fb3811> in <module>
      4 
      5 for w in wordVec:
----> 6     if w not in stopWords:
      7         wordsFiltered.append(w)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I'm well aware I cannot hash over a list. I looked at my tweets and each set of words is all within their own list. I'm very well aware of whats going on but is there any workaround to this issue?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You said you're well aware of what's going on, but are you? `wordVec` is not a list of strings, it's a list of lists of strings.

So when you say:
`for w in wordVec:`

`w` is not a word, it's a list of words.
Which means if you say:

`if w not in stopWords:`

You are asking if the current list of words is in the set. You can't put lists in sets because they are mutable and cannot be hashed, hence the error.

I'm guessing what you really wanted to do is to iterate over the lists of words, and then to iterate over the words in the current list.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


tweets = [
    "Who here likes cheese? I myself like cheese.",
    "Do you have cheese? Do they have cheese?"
]

tokenized_tweets = [nltk.word_tokenize(tweet) for tweet in tweets]
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

filtered_tweets = []

for tokenized_tweet in tokenized_tweets:
    filtered_tweets.append(" ".join(word for word in tokenized_tweet if word.casefold() not in stop_words))

print(filtered_tweets)
```

Output:

```
['likes cheese ? like cheese .', 'cheese ? cheese ?']
```

I just arbitrarily decided to join the list of filtered words before appending them to the `filtered_tweets` list - as you can see it results in the punctuation being separated by whitespace, which might be undesirable. In any case you don't need to join the words back into a string, you can just append the list itself.

Comment: I tried this, seemed like a legit attempt but when running it in my word2vec model, it now does not recognise words in the vocabulary that are clearly there. If you want me to go further I can show you the results of this, but I appreciate your attempt thank you

Comment: @Conor McNally Sure, I'd be curious to see. Maybe update your original post with more info/code?

Answer (score 1):

your variable `wordVec` is a list of lists, so when you are doing:

```
for w in wordVec:
    if w not in stopWords:
```

you check if a list is in  a set, `w` is a list so you get

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

you can fix:

```
for w in wordVec:
    word_tokenize.append([e for e in w if e not in stop_words]))
```

or you could use a list comprehension:

```
word_tokenize = [[e for e in w if e not in stop_words] for w in wordVec]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
text = 'hello my friend, how are you today, are you ok?'
tokenized_word=word_tokenize(text)
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
stops = []
for w in tokenized_word:
    if w not in stop_words:
        stops.append(w)
print(stops)
```

Comment: For this to be a reasonable answer maybe elaborate more on the fact that instead of processing the list at once you process individual words in it.